# Open Liberty support Network Deployment?

Tags: open-liberty

1. Does Open Liberty support network deployment?
2. Are we able to buy IBM Support for Open Liberty? and How?
3. Can Open Liberty be used to replace WebSphere Application server v9 in HA environment? e.g Having Load balancer (hardware) received request from web application and auto distribute received request to 2 or more standalone Open Liberty installed in separate VM/Machine?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify "support network deployment"?

Comment: means for Open Liberty, am I allowed to install adminCenter, collectiveController and collectiveMember features?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so I'll try my best.

> Does Open Liberty support network deployment?

Depends what you mean by that support. You can install multiple Open Liberty on multiple VM/machines that will serve your applications and use LB/or IHS to route to them.
You cannot centrally manage via single console, for that you need WebSphere Liberty ND version that supports collectives.

However most recent deployments will use more 'farm' like or container orchestration approaches rather than central management via dedicated manager (as Dmgr in WAS v9).

> Are we able to buy IBM Support for Open Liberty? and How?

Yes you can. See [Get IBM or Red Hat support for Open Liberty](https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/11/07/ibm-red-hat-support-open-liberty.html) page for general info and contact IBM sales representative for best option for your needs.

> Can Open Liberty be used to replace WebSphere Application server v9 in HA environment?

Depends on your application and non-functional requirements. You can setup LB or IHS with plugin (for more intelligent balancing) to route requests to multiple VM/machines with Open Liberty.

Check for example this [Configuring IBM HTTP Server for Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTJ_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_install_config_liberty.html) and here [Open Liberty Plugin Configuration](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/config/#pluginConfiguration.html). Few manual steps will be needed to edit generated config file to support many servers.